# Progress OpenEdge ERROR [60] [DataDirect][ODBC 20101 driver]6013

Tags: c#, docker, odbc, openedge, unixodbc

I have issue when trying to connect to a progress openedge database using odbc. The client code is in c# and running in docker. Here is my code :

```
using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("DSN=PROGRESS;UID=username;PWD=pass;"))
{
    cn.Open();
}
```

The issue is that program is crashing at the `cn.Open()` with the following error : ERROR [60] [DataDirect][ODBC 20101 driver]6013.

I can successfully connect using `isql -v PROGRESS username pass` and I can query tables.

Environnement :
It is a .NET Core app on a docker environment. Here is my odbc.ini file :

```
[PROGRESS]
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pgoe27.so
HostName=192.168.2.11
DatabaseName=dbname
LogonID=username
Password=pass
PortNumber=20000

[ODBC]
Trace=0
TraceFile=odbctrace.out
TraceDll=/usr/lib/openedge/lib/pgtrc27.so
InstallDir=/usr/lib/openedge
```

I do not understand why I can connect using isql but not using c# OdbcConnection...
Thanks in advance

**EDITED**

Here is my odbc folder permissions :

```
# ls -l lib
total 27124
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1782648 Aug  2 13:09 libodbc.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1280424 Aug  2 13:09 libodbcinst.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14682952 Aug  2 13:09 libpgicu27.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1468736 Aug  2 13:09 libpgmback.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2351288 Aug  2 13:09 libpgssl27.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1586488 Aug  2 13:09 odbccurs.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2871272 Aug  2 13:09 pgoe27.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1667632 Aug  2 13:09 pgtrc27.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    63800 Aug  2 13:09 vscnctdlg.so

# ls -lR locale
locale:
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Aug  2 13:09 en_US

locale/en_US:
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Aug  2 13:09 LC_MESSAGES

locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES:
total 208
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 36241 Aug  2 13:09 odbc.m
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 19099 Aug  2 13:09 odbc.po
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 19096 Aug  2 13:09 pgmback.mo
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 11581 Aug  2 13:09 pgmback.po
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 72722 Aug  2 13:09 pgoe27.mo
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 47627 Aug  2 13:09 pgoe27.po
```

I have managed connecting specifying connection in my .net program, but I still cannot using DSN + odbc.ini  :

```
OdbcConnectionStringBuilder builder = new OdbcConnectionStringBuilder
{
    Driver = "/usr/lib/openedge/lib/pgoe27.so",
};
builder.Add("HostName", "192.168.2.11");
builder.Add("DatabaseName", "PROGRESS");
builder.Add("LogonID", "username");
builder.Add("Password", "password");
builder.Add("PortNumber", "20000");


using (OdbcConnection cnGlims = new OdbcConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
{
    cnGlims.Open();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Progress Knowledgebase the fact that you are getting error numbers (60, 6013) rather than an error message indicates a configuration problem preventing the message description files from being loaded.

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Knowledge/3556 says:

> Cause: The ODBC driver manager and/or the ODBC driver library cannot
> load its message files.
>
> InstallDir is not set correctly in the [ODBC] section of the odbc.ini
> file or the message files in locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES are missing.
>
> Make sure the following are set correctly:
>
> Set the environment variable LANG to en_US :
>
> ```
>   export LANG=en_US (ksh shell)
>   setenv LANG en_US (csh shell)
> ```
>
> Ensure that the environment variable ODBCINI (or ODBC_INI) is pointing
> to the proper odbc.ini file
>
> Ensure that in the [ODBC] section of your odbc.ini file the correct
> installation path of the ODBC drivers is specified for InstallDir
> e.g. InstallDir=/opt/odbc
>
> Make sure the .mo / .po messages files exist
> (odbcinstaldir/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES) and can be loaded by your
> application

If your installDir is /usr/lib/openedge then you should test for the existence (and permissions) of these files like so:

```
$ cd /usr/lib/openedge

$ ls -l ./odbc/lib
total 29832
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 root root  1676480 Jan 21  2020 libodbcinst.so
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 root root  2182544 Jan 21  2020 libodbc.so
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 root root 14682952 Jan 21  2020 libpgicu27.so
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 root root  1977640 Jan 21  2020 libpgmback.so
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 root root  2359016 Jan 21  2020 libpgssl27.so
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 root root  2065616 Jan 21  2020 odbccurs.so
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 root root  3383128 Jan 21  2020 pgoe27.so
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 root root  2142864 Jan 21  2020 pgtrc27.so
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 root root    63800 Jan 21  2020 vscnctdlg.so

$ ls -lR ./odbc/locale
./odbc/locale:
total 0
drwxrwxrwx. 3 root root 25 Apr 10  2020 en_US

./odbc/locale/en_US:
total 0
drwxrwxrwx. 2 root root 105 Apr 10  2020 LC_MESSAGES

./odbc/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES:
total 212
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root root 36241 Jan 21  2020 odbc.m
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root root 19099 Jul 29  2011 odbc.po
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root root 19096 Jan 21  2020 pgmback.mo
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root root 11581 Jul 29  2011 pgmback.po
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root root 74007 Jan 21  2020 pgoe27.mo
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root root 49045 Jan 21  2020 pgoe27.po
```

Comment: Please see edited post, seems everything like you !

Comment: Please see edited post, I have managed connecting specifying connection in my .net program, but I still cannot using DSN + odbc.ini ...